# Show text after choosing option from dropdown menu

Tags: php, html, css

how Can i change this code to show the contents of File after choosing option on the same page instead of redirecting to new page ?

```
    <div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="file1.txt">Option 1</a>
    <a href="file2.txt">Option 2</a>
    <a href="file3.txt">Option 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nothing in the code you've shown would redirect to a new page. Is this code part of a `<form` which has an `action` specifying a particular page to submit to? Or is there some Javascript to handle the selecting of an option or the clicking of the button, and then redirecting the browser perhaps? Provide a [mre] of the issue, please. And, are you wanting to avoid any kind of page refresh at all, or just avoid redirecting to a _different_ page?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP to open and read the ".txt" file you want.

```
function showFile(){
    $myfile = fopen("file1.txt", "r") or die("Unable to open file!");
    echo fread($myfile,filesize("file1.txt"));
    fclose($myfile);
}
```

With this code the content of the file will be displayed in your page. You can use ajax to call this function to open the desired file.